# External hardware to emulate BIOS power management (stay off, turn on, last state)

Tags: bios, power-supply

I have multiple scientific devices, each with an embedded computer and a no-frills BIOS. The single feature I *really* miss is the power management setting that specifies what to do after power loss:

- Stay off
- Always turn on
- Last state

The BIOS is of the 'Always turn on' type -- which is, frankly, the stupidest option of the three considering these scientific devices cost more than my annual salary. They are routinely deployed in situations where power is not guaranteed, like on a generator (a nice one but still). Naturally, I cannot upgrade the BIOS or replace the computer.

I've tried a UPS and that's a no-go. So I've been looking for an external device to sit between the power outlet and the analyzer which can provide this missing feature. Alas, my search-fu is just not up to par.

Does anyone know where I might find such a device? Or maybe an official name I can search for? Or even maybe build one?

To be clear, I'd prefer to have both "Last state" and "Stay off" options but I'd be satisfied with just "Stay off."

Comment: You can use a GPIB connection to do something with perhaps something like a small computer like a raspberry pi that when it goes through a startup routine resets the device setting

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally hit upon some useful search phrases:

- restart protection device
- anti-restart plug
- manual reset GFCI

The kinds of devices these searches result in are not *exactly* what I described in my question as they generally only provide "stay off" behavior. But as I said, that's good enough for me.